# get the parent id of an <li> tag on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
<li><span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="parent overflow">Child<a><img src="../training/Test/Images/TDelete.png" class="iconTR" title="Delete Activity" width="13" id="1" height="13"></a></span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="parent overflow">grand Child<a><img src="../training/Test/Images/TDelete.png" class="iconTR" title="Delete Activity" id="2" width="13" height="13"></a></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="parent overflow">Child<a><img src="../training/Test/Images/TDelete.png" class="iconTR" title="Delete Activity" id="3" width="13" height="13"></a></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </span></li>
</ul>
```

This is my code and I would like to get the `Id` of the immediate parent `li` tag on click of that image . That is when I click on the image of one `li` ,it should alert the `id` of the image in parent li.It would be very helpful if some you provide me the solution.

Comment: where is your click handler for the `li`?

Comment: As I see there're no `id`s in code you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('img').click(function(){

alert($(this).closest('li').parent().closest('li').find('img').attr('id'));

 });
```

> on click of the image the id of the parent li will be alerted

Answer (score 1):

Sooo, something like this?

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');

    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: @Swapna its going to be undefined since no id attributes has been found on your example markup

Comment: Because you don't have an id attribute in your code.

Comment: Ohhh, I understand what you're trying to do now.

Comment: I have id for the img tag

Comment: i want to alert that value

Comment: @Swapna `get the parent id of an <li> tag on click jquery`? then your question is misleading, you should have said that from the beginning,  you're trying to get the id attribute value of the anchor

Comment: No @Ghost, he's trying to get the `id` of the `img` tag at the next higher level. So, in his example, if you click on the `img` with an `id` of 2, it would alert 1, from the `id` of the `img` one more level up.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the immediate parent of the clicked image using the .parent() function of Jquery

So your click handler will be like:

```
$(document).on('click','.iconTR',function(){
   var parent = $(this).parent();
}
```

This will give you the immediate parent of the img tag which is clicked

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8godqng/)

Answer (score 0):

For alerting image id, you need:

```
$('.iconTR').click(function(){
 var imgid= $(this).attr('id');//or this.id
 alert(imgid);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c8uq4ke1/)**

Comment: When i click on an image ,,i want to diaplay the id of the image in its parent li ,

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').click(function(){
var id = $('this').parent().attr('id');
alert(id);
})
```

Then you will get the id of parent li.